# How do you divide a string in python?

Tags: python

I have a string in the form of ( + m1 + "|" + m2 + ) and ( + m1 + "." + m2 + )
where m1 an m2 are strings made up of "6", "7", "8", "a".
These are some of the valid expressions:

```
"(6|7)"
"((8.7)|(6.7).(a.2))"
```

Now my question is, if I want to split at the "." basically that works a a divisor, how would I do that?

What I did was tried finding a middle point but the thing is it's not always in the middle.
I also tried doing s.rindex(".") and s.index(".") and s.find(".") but they also don't seem to work.

I was thinking of calling the outer most brackets and then work it's way inside 
but I don't think that's gonna work.

I am thinking there is some relation perhaps with the brackets but I just can't seem to figure out what it is.
Any suggestion on how do I approach this problem? or hint about how i can find that splitting point?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: your_string.split('.') or your_string.split('|')

Comment: how are they strings made up of `"6", "7", "8", "a"`?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: As a side note, `.` is a terrible choice for a divisor. For example "6.7" is a float 6.7 or two integers 6 and 7?

Comment: You would have to split by `").("` then some how get the parenthesis back on the result

Comment: @Marcin: it's a perfectly fine choice of separator as long as the numbers are integers. (Admittedly visually less clear than '|',';',':' )

Comment: @Diana: is your expected output just a **flat list** of strings or integers ['8','7','6','7','a','2']? or a **parse-tree** (which is where we would use the parens)?

Comment: @Diana we are asking to you only. Could you say hi to confirm you're not a bot?

Comment: my expected output is to return true if it's a valid expression, false otherwise.

Comment: @jakeimds i tried doing that, however I ma using recursion it gives e false all the time

Comment: is there a way I can deal with the inner bracket first??

Answer (score 0):

This is my interpretation of what you're asking. Without more information, an explicitly stated problem, expected output, or code showing your own attempts, I can't do much more.

```
test1 = "(6|7)"
test2 = "((8.7)|(6.7).(a.2))"
# Not really sure what your output is suppose to look
# Like so this is my interpretation 
test1_split = test1.replace("(", "").replace(")", "").split("|")
print test1_split # output --> ['6', '7'] 
                  # creates a list containing the string 6 and 7
# You said the . works an a divisor.  If you mean a delimiter then you can use the split("."") method
# If you mean that it is a symbol for a divide sign then see below
test2 = test2.replace(".", "/") # convert periods into dividing sign
test2_split = test2.split("|")  # seperates (8/7) (6/7)/(a/2))
print test2_split # output ['((8/7)', '(6/7)/(a/2))']

# now if this is an equation I would continue...Since I don't know the output
# I leave the rest to you
```

Comment: Thank you soo much, I think I have an idea now of what to do.